# Images not displaying in Laravel 4

Tags: css, laravel-4

I'm having troubles with this - The images are not displaying

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
        @foreach ($model->pictures as $picture) 

             <div class="fill" 
                style="background-image:url({{ URL::asset($picture->path) }});">
                </div>

          <!--   {{ HTML::image($picture->path)}}    -->        
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

if I go to the view source the image is alright, actually I pasted the result in the url and works. By the way in the example i have a commented line that works, but I need the image as a background in a div and not actually as an html tag.
What could it be?

the fill class on css:

```
.fill {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the class "fill" doesn't have the height nor the width. Since you are defining a background for an element that does not have any size, the element itself (ie: the div) is now being showed.

You can resolve this by defining the width and height, like this:

```
<div class="fill"
    style="background:url({{ URL::asset($picture->path) }}); no-repeat;
            background-size:269px 95px;height:95px;width:269px">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try and change the width and height from 100% to 100px and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;background-image:url('{{ asset('http://www.example.com/images/image.png') }}'); border-radius: 5px;position:relative">
```

Instead of using:

```
URL::asset($picture->path
```

You can use the `absolute` path to the image.

For example:

```
http://www.example.com/images/image.png
```

Also, try using `width` in `px` instead of in `%`

**Note:** It is better to avoid inline styling but since you are already using it for the `background-image`, I would just go ahead!